# Missing ext-dom when running composer update in Yii2 project

Tags: php, yii2, ubuntu-18.04, yii2-advanced-app

I am getting this error every time I run composer update in my Yii2 framework project:

[image]

```
Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.5.0, ..., 9.5.28] require ext-dom * -> 
      it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ~9.5.0 -> 
      satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.5.0, ..., 9.5.28].
```

I have tried running run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-dom` but returns the same error.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is indicating that the phpunit/phpunit package requires the ext-dom extension, but it is not installed or enabled on your system.

To resolve this issue, you need to install the ext-dom extension on your system. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

After installing the ext-dom extension, try running composer update again to see if the issue has been resolved. If you continue to experience the same error, you may need to restart your web server or check your PHP configuration to ensure that the ext-dom extension is properly loaded.

Comment: Thank you but I have tried this several times but still haven't solved the issue on my Linux machine.